# Compiler error: Can not find symbol

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TestPerson {

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of <code>TestPerson</code>.
     */
    public TestPerson() {
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        MemberType[] m = { new MemberType("Corporate Member"),new MemberType("VIP Member")
        };
        RegMember[] r = new RegMember[2];
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        for(int i=0;i<r.length;i++){

            System.out.println("your reg no is :"+(RegMember.getNextNo()+1));
            for(int a=0;a<m.length;a++){
                System.out.println((a+1)+". "+m[a].toString());
            }
            System.out.println("Enter Your selection:");
            int sel=s.nextInt();
            if(sel==1){
                s.nextLine(); 
                System.out.println(" enter name:");
                    String Name=s.nextLine();
                System.out.println(" enter Handphone:");
                    String Hpnum=s.next();
                System.out.println(" enter Age:");
                    int age=s.nextInt();
                System.out.println("enter Company Name:");
                    String CompanyName=s.nextLine();
                Cmember cm = new Cmember(Name,Hpnum,age,CompanyName);   
            }
            else{
                s.nextLine();
                System.out.println(" enter name:");
                    String Name=s.nextLine();
                System.out.println(" enter Handphone:");
                    String Hpnum=s.next();
                System.out.println(" enter Age:");
                    int age=s.nextInt();
                System.out.println("enter Email:");
                    String email=s.next();
                Vipmember vip = new Vipmember(Name,Hpnum,age,email);
            }
            if(sel==1){
                r[i]=new RegMember(cm);

            }
            else{
                r[i]=new RegMember(vip);
            }
            s.nextLine(); 
        }

            displayInfor(r);
    }
    public static void displayInfor( RegMember[]r){

    for(int i =0; i<r.length;i++)
    System.out.println( r[i].toString());
    }

}
```

The problem is that I get this error.

```
60: error: cannot find symbol
                r[i]=new RegMember(cm);

                                   ^   symbol:   variable cm

  location: class TestPerson

64: error: cannot find symbol
                r[i]=new RegMember(vip);

                                   ^   symbol:   variable vip

  location: class TestPerson 2 errors
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Cmember cm=null;
 Vipmember vip=null;
if(sel==1){
            ...
           cm = new Cmember(Name,Hpnum,age,CompanyName);   
        }
        else{
            ...
           vip = new Vipmember(Name,Hpnum,age,email);
        }
        if(sel==1){
            r[i]=new RegMember(cm);

        }
        else{
            r[i]=new RegMember(vip);
        }
        s.nextLine();
```

Basically, cm and vip were not in the scope when you were trying to use them

Answer (score -1):

That is because simply compiler can't find the variable that you mention. You have declared variables in blocks. So outside the block they are not exist. You must declare your variables in appropriate places so you can access them.

Comment: why my answer get -1?